# Image sprite has white background and wrong position

Tags: image, background, sprite

I am not very experienced with image sprites so here is the question..

I made an image sprite on the web; this is the code:

```
.sprite-slidebutton {
    background-position: 0 0;
    width: 70px;
    height: 63px;

}

.sprite-slidecross {
    background-position: 0 -113px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 63px;   
}
```

The image I got, I downloaded to my page and I called the .png wherever wanted it. It does appear! And the sprite is working, the image is switching like i want it to..

But the PNG is not showing a transparent background :S also the image is not in the middle, I only see half of the both images.. where and how to adjust?

To see it live:

solved

Answer (score 0):

If i had to guess i would say there is a problem with the alpha values in the image. Download gimp and see what they are.

Answer (score 0):

the png probably has a white background, instead of a transparent background.  that's something you will need to edit in photoshop, gimp or similar.

as far as only seeing half the image it might be due to the element you are assigning the class to.  if its an inline element like `<a>` or `<span>`.  try adding "display:block;" inside the sprite-slidebutton class.

Comment: thx, I indeed had to make the background transparent haha. I thought I did, but it was not configured correctly in my psp